# Why is the call of this three annotations is the same?

Tags: java, spring, scope, annotations

I m reading about Spring Framework 5.

As stated in the book the `@Scope` annotation code is like below

```
@Target({ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.METHOD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
public @interface Scope {
        @AliasFor("scopeName")
        String value() default "";
        @AliasFor("value")
        String scopeName() default "";
        ScopedProxyMode proxyMode() default ScopedProxyMode.DEFAULT;
}
```

Then they are mentioning that the three following calls are the same :

> @Scope(ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_SINGLETON)

> @Scope(value = ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_SINGLETON)

> @Scope(scopeName = ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_SINGLETON)

I have understood that  `value` and `scopeName` are interchangeable, but for my understanding they are not referencing the `proxyMode`.

I was  expecting that the first one is not the same as the second and the third, here is what I Believed to be true :

> value="" ; socopeName =""; proxyMode = SCOPE_SINGLETON

> value="SCOPE_SINGLETON" ; socopeName ="SCOPE_SINGLETON"; proxyMode = DEFAULT

> value="SCOPE_SINGLETON" ; socopeName ="SCOPE_SINGLETON"; proxyMode = DEFAULT

What happens under the hood, that this three are the same ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the javadoc of [`value()`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Scope.html#value--) says:

> Alias for [`scopeName()`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Scope.html#scopeName--).

That is only true because the code that *uses* the annotation makes it so. It is the code that calls `scopeName()` that will turn around and call `value()` if the first call returned the default value `""`.

It is the Java Language Specification that makes the following the same:

```java
@Scope(ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_SINGLETON)
@Scope(value = ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_SINGLETON)
```

The Java Language Specification, section [9.7.3. Single-Element Annotations](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se15/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.7.3), says:

> A *single-element annotation*, is a shorthand designed for use with single-element annotation types ([§9.6.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se15/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.6.1)).
>
> > *SingleElementAnnotation:*
> > @ [*TypeName*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se15/html/jls-6.html#jls-TypeName) ( [*ElementValue*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se15/html/jls-9.html#jls-ElementValue) )
>
> It is shorthand for the normal annotation:
>
> > @*TypeName*(value = *ElementValue*)